# Regular expression in table

Tags: tables, extended-characters

I want to print a regular expression in table's column. For example:

```
\begin{table}[position specifier]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c }
        \hline
        comand & regex \\ 
        \hline
        HELO & ^\s*HELO\s+(\S+)\s*$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:smtp}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But, I have a lot of errors due to `^\s*HELO\s+(\S+)\s*$`. So, what does the simplest way to escape this regex?

**EDIT:**

I do not have enough reputation to ask to my own question. So the most suitable solution is to use `\verb` comand.

Comment: I've found a good solution for my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/2528843/1160443. Do you know any others?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Please provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) that clearly shows your problem. This should start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}.

Comment: The solution offered on stackoverflow is the most natural one, in my opinion. If it suits you perfectly, you should post your end-command in an answer to that question, with a word of explanation. If you have any problem with it (even if it is syntax clumsiness), you should edit your question with that suggestion and an explanation about why you are looking for something else.

Comment: Oh, right, the reputation issue. I've added this answer as community wiki then.

Answer (score 4):

From the comments and [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2528843/1160443), a solution is to use `\verb`, for example this way :

```
\verb!^\s*HELO\s+(\S+)\s*$!
```

Comment: If you have many such regular expressions, you can use the `shortvrb` package to define for instance `"` to be a shorthand for `\verb"`.  Then it would be used as `"^\s*HELO\s+(\S+)\s*$"`.